# How to make JS run in every instance of carousel

Tags: javascript, carousel

I have tried for hours to get my code, which works perfectly only on the first instance to run on every instance and cannot figure it out.

I want the read more to not show when it's not needed, and it does it correctly, only the first time.

I have tried different variables, let, and const, lastly, I tried to add a function, but it keeps not working.

```js
// Runs only on first instance

var element = document.querySelector('.short-text'); 
if(element) { 
    document.querySelector('.read-more-button').setAttribute('hidden', true);
}

// My attempt to run every time

function myFunction() {
    var elements = document.querySelector('.short-text');
    if(elements) { 
        document.querySelector('.read-more-button').setAttribute('hidden', true);
    }
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: Do you want to run `setAttribute('hidden', true)` for the `read-more-button` for every element with class `short-text`?

Comment: Yes! Right now, in the carousel, it only runs on the first one, but not the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Because [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first element only. You should use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and iterate through the returned elements.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".short-text");

elements.forEach((item) => {
    let button = item.querySelector(".read-more-button");
    if (button) {
        button.setAttribute('hidden',true);
    }
});
```

or

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".short-text .read-more-button");

elements.forEach((item) => {
    item.setAttribute('hidden',true);    
});
```

Comment: :/ does not seem to work.

I added it globally or in every element and it still did not work. you can see a page i am trying to add it here: https://garrettclaimsgroup.com/testing-carousel/

Thank you so much for your help